# Can ConcurrentQueue<T> dequeue same item multiple times?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I was using ConcurrentQueue to manage a queue of items to be elaborated in parallel when I realized that some items are elaborated multiple times.

I tought that ConcurrentQueue was thread safe, but now I have this doubt, is it possible that the method TryDequeue, if accessed in parallel at same time can return the same item twice in different threads?

**Edit**
I am not asking why my code is not working, so pretend a reproducible example is useless,  but yes the question is a bit stupid, you can find an answer easily searching on Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1.trydequeue?view=netframework-4.8#remarks):

Comment: I expect something with `Concurrent` in its name to be intended to be thread-safe by definition. Are you really sure you can dequeue the same item twice? According to MSDN, a ConcurrentQueue "Represents a thread-safe first in-first out (FIFO) collection."

Comment: Please elaborate with a [mre]. Chances are that you're _enqueuing_ the same item multiple times.

Comment: We will have to see some code.

Comment: I have not posted code, because I am not asking you to fix my problem. I already found another solution using semaphores. I am not saying that I am sure that the problem is related to ConcurrentQueue  and I am not asking why TryDequeque returns the same element twice.
I am asking, if TryDequeque  can return the same element twice or not. If yes, ok I learned something new, if no, I'll try investigate further the reason of my issue.

Comment: It cannot. From the documentation: `TryDequeue tries to remove an element from the queue. If the method is successful, the item is removed and the method returns true; otherwise, it returns false. That happens atomically with respect to other operations on the queue.` The key phrase here is **That happens atomically with respect to other operations on the queue**

Answer (score 4):

No, an item dequeued by only one thread. ConcurrentQueue manages concurrency.

> ConcurrentQueue handles all synchronization internally. If two threads call TryDequeue at precisely the same moment, neither operation is blocked. When a conflict is detected between two threads, one thread has to try again to retrieve the next element, and the synchronization is handled internally.

[ConcurrentQueue.TryDequeue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1.trydequeue?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 2):

[The docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1.trydequeue?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) disagree:

> `TryDequeue` tries to remove an element from the queue. If the method is successful, the item is removed and the method returns `true`; otherwise, it returns `false`. That happens atomically with respect to other operations on the queue. If the queue was populated with code such as `q.Enqueue("a"); q.Enqueue("b"); q.Enqueue("c");` and two threads concurrently try to dequeue an element, one thread will dequeue `a` and the other thread will dequeue `b`. Both calls to `TryDequeue` will return `true`, because they were both able to dequeue an element.

If you're seeing behaviour which is different to this, we'll need a sample which reproduces it. I suspect your problem is elsewhere.